# Make Axis and ticks invisible in mathematica plot, but keep labels

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to make a mathematica plot with no visible y-axis, but retaining the tick labels.

I've tried AxesStyle -> {Thickness[.001], Thickness[0]} with no effect, and setting the opacity to 0 also makes the tick labels fully transparent (and thus invisible).

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 AxesStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0]},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black]]

ticks = AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks];

ticks[[1, 2, 2]] = DeleteCases[ticks[[1, 2, 2]], {_, "", __}];

ticks[[1, 2, 2, All, 3]] = ConstantArray[{0, 0},
   Length[ticks[[1, 2, 2, All, 3]]]];

ticks[[1, 2, 2, All, 2]] = Map[ToString,
    ticks[[1, 2, 2, All, 2]]] /. a_String :>
    If[StringTake[a, -1] == ".", a <> "0", a];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 AxesStyle -> {Black, Directive[Opacity[0], Red]},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black],
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks[[1, 2, 2]]}]
```

[image]

To get the exact original ticks you can use

```
Cases[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@ PlotRange[p][[2]], {_, _}]
```

> {{-1.,-1.0},{-0.5,-0.5},{0.,0},{0.5,0.5},{1.,1.0}}

as implemented here:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
   AxesStyle -> {Automatic, Opacity[0]},
   TicksStyle -> Opacity[1]];
ticks = AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks];
onestyledtick = ticks[[1, 2, 2, 1]];
labels = Cases[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@
    PlotRange[p][[2]], {_, _}];
yticks = Map[Join[#, {{0, 0}},
     Take[onestyledtick, -1]] &, labels];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 AxesStyle -> {Automatic, Opacity[0]},
 TicksStyle -> Opacity[1],
 Ticks -> {Automatic, yticks}]
```

Comment: Related note: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97317/absoluteoptions-doesnt-return-correct-option-value-of-ticks

Comment: Great -- this definitely work (and glad to see that it can't be done just be setting an option when you make the plot :-)